# VBA Cutting string after last word less than 80 characters total length

Tags: string, excel, vba, character

I am:

- using the Excel `Clean` function to strip all formatting off any text, and
- then I want to break the resulting long string into separate rows of 80 characters or less.
- the only delimiter remaining after the clean is a white space.

The code below does this like a champ but it is brutal;

**Code**

```
Sub TrimTo75()

myRow = 4
Range("C" & myRow).Select
myString = ActiveCell.Value

While myString <> ""
While Len(myString) > 75

mySubString = Left(myString, 75)
ActiveCell.Value = mySubString

myString = Right(myString, Len(myString) - 75)

myRow = myRow + 1
Range("C" & myRow).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

If Len(myString) < 75 Then    
ActiveCell.Value = myString    
End If

Wend

myRow = myRow + 1
Range("C" & myRow).Select
myString = ActiveCell.Value

Wend        
End Sub
```

Comment: I did ask a question on how to improve this function- I want to add functionality to it by stopping at the end of the last word before 80 characters.
I am not answering my question but looking for some assistance in making it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..

```
Sub TrimTo75()

myRow = 4
Range("C" & myRow).Select
myString = ActiveCell.Value
Dim x As Integer

While myString <> ""

  While Len(myString) >= 75
    x = 75
    While Not Mid(myString, x, 1) = " "
      x = x - 1
    Wend

    MsgBox x

    'mySubString = Left(myString, 75)
    mySubString = Left(myString, x)
    ActiveCell.Value = mySubString

    'myString = Right(myString, Len(myString) - 75)
    myString = Mid(myString, x + 1)

    myRow = myRow + 1
    Range("C" & myRow).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    If Len(myString) < 75 Then

      ActiveCell.Value = myString

    End If

  Wend

  myRow = myRow + 1
  Range("C" & myRow).Select
  myString = ActiveCell.Value

Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: This almost works; it does parse out the text upside down (first line on bottom) but that isnt a big deal, easy fix. The problem is that it bugs out after a few lines are parsed.
Does not like the " ActiveCell.Value = mySubString"

Comment: It errors out after about 3 lines of conversion; goes into infinite processing and I have to break the macro just to look at the debugger

Comment: @Mark .. It works with me with more than 3 lines .. (tested 9 lines) .. Maybe caused by some strange string ! .. May I know it ?

Comment: I was able to get it to work with one quirk- the first line that is being copied over is missing. Any ideas where this is going?

Answer (score 1):

This code uses a `Regex` and a variant array for quick parsing

It takes a range from `C4:Cx` and places the chunks in `D4` down

```
Sub QuickStrip()
Dim Regex As Object
Dim RegexMC As Object
Dim RegexM As Object
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim lngOut As Long

X = Range([c4], Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With Regex
.Pattern = "[\w\s]{1,79}([^\w]|$)"
.Global = True
For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X)
If .test(X(lngCnt, 1)) Then
    Set RegexMC = .Execute(X(lngCnt, 1))
    For Each RegexM In RegexMC
    [d4].Offset(lngOut, 0) = RegexM
    lngOut = lngOut + 1
    Next
End If
Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I like this and it seems to almost work perfectly; the only issue is that it is not breaking the lines into 80ish characters in length. Many are single words. Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Do you have a sample that isn't working as yu would prefer that you could add to your initial question?

Answer (score 0):

```
If Len(rngCellsB_Title) > 90 Then                                    
    x = 90

    While Not Mid(rngCellsB_Title, x, 1) = " "
       x = x - 1
    Wend

    strFirstPart = Left(rngCellsB_Title, x)
    strSecondPart = Right(rngCellsB_Title, (Len(rngCellsB_Title) - x))
    blnSplit = True
End If

If blnSplit Then

   strMessageTemp = strFirstPart & strSecondPart & Chr(13)

   blnSplit = False

Else
   strMessageTemp = rngCellsB_Title & Chr(13)
End If
```

Try this, it simply splits the string before a known point using the space as a demiliter.  I used a simple boolean to test for before processing either the whole string, or 2 parts of it.